# Redirect traffic to another IP and Port

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, iptables

I have a Virtual Machine with a random virtual IP. I'm able to retrieve its IP with the following command line:

```
VM_IP=$(some command)
```

What I'd like to get is something that would redirect my local traffic like that:

- `http://MY_MACHINE:8080` to `http://VM_IP:80`
- `https://MY_MACHINE:4443` to `https://VM_IP:443`

I've tried with iptables but there are too many existing entries and I don't want to break something.
I've also enable `net.ipv4.ip_forward`.

The problem is mainly that the `VM_IP` can change once a day (because of hardware switched off).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too broad to give a solution that works out of the box, but here are the rough steps you need to follow:

- Install a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) on your machine, e.g. [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/)
- On restart set the `VM_IP` environment variable of the system
- Use that environment variable in the reverse proxy configuration, which can map port 8080 of your machine to port 80 of the VM and same for port 4443 and 443.

  - You can use [`envsubst`](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/using-envsubst-to-merge-environment-variables-into-config-files) to replace the VM IP with the value from the environment variable
  - If you use docker compose you can [use that](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration-new-in-119) to set the VM IP.
  - If you use docker and your VM is also a docker container you could consider [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy) image to set this all up in an easier way.